Elasticsearch RequestError(400) 'search_phase_execution_exception'
I have a simple python app that uses Elasticsearch to store documents for Pokemon using this mapping:
{


"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "base": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "species": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "evolution": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "profile": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "ability": {
            "type": "keyword"  
          }
        }
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "embedding": {  
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 384
      }
    }
  }
}

When I query by a property for example name in english from my python code:
term_query = {
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name.english": "Pikachu"
        }
    }
}

response = es_client.search(index="pokemon", body=term_query)
print(response)

I do get back the document for Pikachu. This is the response:
{'took': 16, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 1, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': 2.5902672, 'hits': [{'_index': 'pokemon', '_type': '_doc', '_id': 'uTSUE5EB_ikN9OuVrCYz', '_score': 2.5902672, '_source': {'id': 25, 'name': {'english': 'Pikachu', 'japanese': 'ピカチュウ', 'chinese': '皮卡丘', 'french': 'Pikachu'}, 'type': ['Electric'], 'base': {'HP': 35, 'Attack': 55, 'Defense': 40, 'Sp. Attack': 50, 'Sp. Defense': 50, 'Speed': 90}, 'species': 'Mouse Pokémon', 'description': 'While sleeping, it generates electricity in the sacs in its cheeks. If it’s not getting enough sleep, it will be able to use only weak electricity.', 'evolution': {'prev': ['172', 'high Friendship'], 'next': [['26', 'use Thunder Stone']]}, 'profile': {'height': '0.4 m', 'weight': '6 kg', 'egg': ['Field', 'Fairy'], 'ability': [['Static', 'false'], ['Lightning Rod', 'true']], 'gender': '50:50'}, 'image': {'sprite': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Purukitto/pokemon-data.json/master/images/pokedex/sprites/025.png', 'thumbnail': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Purukitto/pokemon-data.json/master/images/pokedex/thumbnails/025.png', 'hires': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Purukitto/pokemon-data.json/master/images/pokedex/hires/025.png'}, 'embedding': [-0.08073285967111588, 0.06939519941806793, 0.12187427282333374, -0.004082795698195696, -0.12248878180980682, -0.20900841057300568, 0.24315859377384186, 0.17423027753829956, 0.16088330745697021, -0.11973902583122253, 0.219094380736351, -0.1787237524986267, 0.14656412601470947, 0.26914048194885254, -0.0900934562087059, -0.02184007130563259, 0.08033201843500137, 0.22495900094509125, -0.2534410059452057, 0.041292887181043625, 0.06425879895687103, -0.23064647614955902, 0.13032366335391998, -0.18455955386161804, -0.27389195561408997, -0.039019424468278885, 0.35004937648773193, -0.015063440427184105, -0.046075183898210526, 0.06129240244626999, -0.2043248414993286, 0.06172535941004753, 0.04312220215797424, 0.08780308812856674, 0.13448253273963928, -0.05551649630069733, -0.1422523856163025, -0.027074327692389488, 0.04502112418413162, -0.1769474595785141, -0.008200257085263729, -0.25519609451293945, 0.13449157774448395, 0.2700392007827759, 0.006515479180961847, 0.5337464809417725, 0.1946619153022766, -0.3672884404659271, -0.12406620383262634, -0.09569848328828812, -0.007241903804242611, 0.3416319191455841, -0.05228937789797783, 0.036399926990270615, -0.22220291197299957, -0.061945606023073196, 0.11898031830787659, -0.18378591537475586, -0.041961733251810074, -0.047705043107271194, -0.17708761990070343, 0.16963569819927216, 0.3308679163455963, 0.04163277521729469, 0.04719669744372368, 0.05068834125995636, -0.26456910371780396, 0.026870373636484146, -0.10195782780647278, 0.23298844695091248, 0.031212573871016502, -0.3020530343055725, 0.1332738697528839, -0.29328441619873047, -0.09723328799009323, 0.12734854221343994, -0.06871715933084488, -0.09589243680238724, -0.0217132605612278, -0.04689288139343262, 0.11232715100049973, -0.1212148666381836, -0.502180814743042, 0.3030500113964081, 0.23431822657585144, 0.20775146782398224, 0.03362984582781792, -0.3450615406036377, -0.38474512100219727, -0.015262553468346596, -0.012009349651634693, 0.5406750440597534, -0.11293786019086838, 0.19005414843559265, -0.15757060050964355, -0.1948317289352417, 0.09620492905378342, -0.2629433870315552, -0.8698116540908813, -0.1905592530965805, 0.007942819967865944, 0.5021940469741821, -0.22358925640583038, 0.28493547439575195, 0.2063635140657425, -0.09802521765232086, -0.12083346396684647, -0.2472897320985794, 0.11121658980846405, 0.2569717764854431, 0.14332978427410126, -0.4158305823802948, -0.21560056507587433, 0.47279030084609985, 0.05417272448539734, 0.15705130994319916, 0.11930802464485168, 0.2766338884830475, -0.16857114434242249, 0.38867419958114624, 0.07035291939973831, -0.19579669833183289, -0.20194637775421143, -0.045491937547922134, 0.22118116915225983, -0.4455321729183197, -0.14013874530792236, 0.08595887571573257, 0.07313554733991623, 0.21260005235671997, 0.011720014736056328, -0.11162177473306656, -0.31165409088134766, -0.18956924974918365, -0.08518164604902267, 0.3265906274318695, 0.3938029110431671, 0.16317987442016602, -0.24403564631938934, 0.2091466188430786, 0.15612895786762238, 0.5397796034812927, -0.021354854106903076, -0.2237994521856308, 0.15890972316265106, -0.1837628185749054, 0.07010602951049805, -0.05256254971027374, -0.06645826995372772, 0.05712897330522537, 0.0011353784939274192, -0.26107025146484375, 0.2231748253107071, 0.03408034145832062, -0.019110316410660744, -0.09659949690103531, -0.20144665241241455, 0.22397348284721375, 0.1376374363899231, 0.09118841588497162, 0.05390686169266701, 0.2291051596403122, -0.22862714529037476, -0.011429731734097004, 0.26337283849716187, 0.008011268451809883, -0.2091754674911499, -0.018558669835329056, -0.3221794664859772, -0.03949500247836113, 0.06667587906122208, 0.1057417243719101, 0.09627758711576462, 0.02740870602428913, 0.13777735829353333, -0.31403109431266785, -0.35416749119758606, -0.06899789720773697, -0.21653032302856445, -0.027547530829906464, 0.10295339673757553, 0.1908693164587021, 0.06642354279756546, -0.2547055780887604, -0.27135589718818665, -0.10589489340782166, 0.07966331392526627, 0.10850854963064194, -0.1262790560722351, -0.2978314459323883, -0.23875080049037933, -0.3113715648651123, 0.20441405475139618, 0.047840893268585205, -0.12133669853210449, -0.025360196828842163, -0.18699155747890472, -0.3434793949127197, -0.011686017736792564, -0.1433863788843155, -0.02858828380703926, -0.2638932764530182, -0.20476993918418884, -0.12419438362121582, 0.028579195961356163, -0.1174812987446785, -0.33529555797576904, -0.20364123582839966, 0.04101632535457611, -0.09168056398630142, -0.05435829237103462, -0.30858591198921204, 0.25615713000297546, 0.1913250833749771, 0.6707220673561096, 0.4516240358352661, -0.10038889944553375, 0.09332328289747238, -0.08849727362394333, -0.04820533096790314, 0.3817048966884613, -0.2124391496181488, -0.20861664414405823, -0.3969747722148895, -0.26697418093681335, -0.09186507016420364, -0.17242462933063507, 0.163199320435524, -0.18881991505622864, 0.08426131308078766, -0.2372647523880005, -0.004029334522783756, 0.06960441172122955, -0.047179535031318665, -0.20344287157058716, 0.183263897895813, -0.06168253347277641, -0.04381486400961876, 0.21352356672286987, -0.29498425126075745, 0.046090275049209595, 0.016421712934970856, -0.03849317133426666, 0.2436819225549698, -0.24784734845161438, 0.06414017081260681, -0.01664029061794281, 0.18358607590198517, 0.025173719972372055, 0.6090837717056274, 0.050406910479068756, 0.1362634152173996, -0.22938694059848785, 0.3377200961112976, 0.13915757834911346, 0.23770390450954437, 0.1720094382762909, 0.030198220163583755, 0.024356193840503693, -0.28200817108154297, -0.19686788320541382, -0.1351262480020523, -0.007643698249012232, -0.22928962111473083, 0.11154638230800629, -0.014717038720846176, 0.1324407309293747, 0.46048006415367126, -0.017119301483035088, -0.4727839231491089, -0.4402349591255188, -0.01458784844726324, -0.04428641498088837, 0.04039650410413742, 0.48811277747154236, -0.3889062702655792, -0.2668595612049103, 0.05276121944189072, -0.1911555528640747, -0.11344823241233826, 0.0762748047709465, -0.19064147770404816, 0.2186267226934433, -0.23358970880508423, 0.15427519381046295, -0.13358311355113983, 0.03089122287929058, -0.26767098903656006, 0.08962049335241318, -0.13496246933937073, 0.10376256704330444, 0.26555293798446655, 0.7292829155921936, 0.12933622300624847, 0.1885850727558136, 0.33418792486190796, -0.0045865499414503574, -0.08271858841180801, -0.19287362694740295, 0.39168789982795715, 0.07085824757814407, 0.16441291570663452, 0.026745975017547607, -0.014314485713839531, -0.10071783512830734, -0.08725757896900177, 0.04012788459658623, -0.22500525414943695, 0.1916060894727707, -0.44129520654678345, -0.34983548521995544, 0.3279268145561218, 0.35589221119880676, -0.014993308112025261, -0.2724052369594574, 0.1550331711769104, -0.16982153058052063, 0.28001534938812256, -0.08957020193338394, 0.26859310269355774, -0.06395307928323746, -0.18223333358764648, -0.03468851372599602, -0.091072678565979, -0.012290200218558311, -0.28910940885543823, 0.08019937574863434, -0.2714097201824188, 0.23566178977489471, -0.15085045993328094, 0.31374698877334595, 0.030088581144809723, 0.1816730797290802, -0.13970644772052765, -0.0039431205950677395, 0.6152960658073425, 0.4371360242366791, 0.03539286553859711, -0.10140117257833481, 0.03148588910698891, -0.16396838426589966, -0.3729839324951172, -0.08252952247858047, -0.10826507955789566, -0.13000987470149994, -0.0005456415819935501, -0.11005621403455734, 0.17918984591960907, -0.3737146556377411, -0.3396584987640381, -0.08200288563966751, 0.14435864984989166, 0.5620496273040771, 0.27496692538261414, 0.004530945792794228, -0.15538428723812103, 0.380673348903656, -0.22902937233448029, 0.22183893620967865, -0.06294988840818405, 0.08632779121398926, -0.5587152242660522, -0.22411471605300903, 0.1320917010307312, -0.1736510843038559, 0.09566263109445572, 0.4774761497974396, -0.009492949582636356, -0.2615973651409149, 0.31702664494514465, -0.11396189033985138, 0.4716211259365082, 0.057476241141557693, -0.05458242818713188, -0.05082737281918526, -0.1389731615781784, 0.22226481139659882, 0.5554996728897095, -0.19391866028308868, 0.24401207268238068, 0.3081281781196594, 0.26846665143966675, 0.13681122660636902, 0.04111223667860031]}}]}}

I checked all the properties and they look correct. The embedding also has the right lenght 384 which is what this model I am using produces: embeddings_model = SentenceTransformer("paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2")
However when I try to run an embedding cosine similarity query like:
query = "Pikachu"
query_embedding = embeddings_model.encode([query])[0].tolist()
script_query_cosine = {
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'embedding') + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": query_embedding
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

response = es_client.search(index="pokemon", body=script_query_cosine)
print(response)

I get this error:
RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
I checked the embedding size and it is correct. I checked if any documents are missing the embeddings fields and I found no documents that miss it. I have no clue what this error is.

Did you try to print script_query_cosine  and execute from the Kibana ? it seems like query formation have some issue. Please print query and see if it correct or not.

Hi @SagarPatel what do you mean print the query string in my python code? Or print the query the client sends? How do I do this? Thank you!

Term is an exact/perfect matching query and Match is fuzzy matching query.
I would suggest you to use match query, instead of term for your case.
GET /pokemon/_search
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.english": "Pikachu"
    }
  }
}

